# Vue inline template and CSP

Tags: vue.js, content-security-policy

I need to add CSP headers to a website. The site uses Vue 2.* for some basic reactivity stuff. Nothing fancy, just some `v-model`, `v-bind` and `v-on`. Likewise it's all used inline; Vue components would be overkill.

Pseudo-code:

```
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <button v-on="toggle">...</button
    </div>
    <script>
        new Vue({
            el: '#app"
        });
    </script>
</body
```

When setting the script CSP header to `Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self';` everything inside the mounted element is rendered blank.

I've [read that a render function should be used](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/08/vue-js-chrome-extension/) instead in order to avoid the `eval()` call in Vue's template compiler, but that brings us back to converting everything to a Vue component.

Is there any alternative that allows me to keep the element's inner content inline in the global HTML file?

Comment: In my case the markup appeared in the HTML source but within the context of the virtual dom the output was `<!---->` or an empty comment block. This was true even with `sha-512` configured to allow 'strict-dynamic'`, and an inline Vue template running under Chromium.

Answer (score 1):

No. If you have Vue markup in the HTML, it's not really HTML, it's a Vue template, and Vue's processing of templates uses `eval`.

The idea that components are overkill suggests that you see them as daunting or esoteric. They're a basic, fundamental part of Vue programming. We use them for lots of very small things. Make a component whose template is the HTML you currently have in your app now. Use the render function in [this article](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/09/17/vue-js-avoid-dom-templates/) to apply it to your div. Done.

Comment: I don't necessarily think components are daunting but in this project all pages mount Vue on a top level div (immediate child of the body tag) to allow it to be used at will for some quick aesthetic sugar.

Comment: I'm in agreement with OP this is overkill. Perhaps they should improve their question with actual code because I just tried this with a search form and was met only with strife.

Comment: I think it's the use of Vue that is overkill in the OP's situation. It's a framework being used for "some quick aesthetic sugar."